# Qt не запускает консольные приложения

Tags: c, qt, debian, c++, linux

Гуглил, находил подобные темы, не помогло...

Имеется Debian 7.0 (KDE)

Установил Qt ( QtCreator 2.5.0 основан на Qt 4.8.2 64x )

Имеется проект (консольное приложение), а в нём main.cpp , который компилируется, но не работает:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "WORK PLEASE" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Нажимаю зелёную стрелку, открывается konsole, а там:

> Cannot connect creator comm socket /tmp/qt_temp.y11358/stub-socket: No such file or directory
>
> Для закрытия данного окна нажмите <ВВОД>...

В Инструменты->Параметры->Среда в графе Терминал заменил "x-terminal-emulator -e" на "xterm". Теперь он вообще не запускает никакой консоли.

В окне "Вывод приложения" каждый раз отрывается новая вкладка, а в ней:

> Запускается
> /home/artyom/qt/shadow/work_please...

Если их закрывать, Qt будет спрашивать "Точно закрыть хотите? Программа ещё выполняется!"

Ну, вроде описал всё, что можно.

Помогите пожалуйста, второй час бьюсь головой в монитор...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток! Проверьте есть ли в файле проекта следующая строчка:

```
CONFIG = console
```

Если нет то добавьте - должно помочь.
Насчет Debian не знаю, но мне на виндовозе помогало. И еще: я так понял, что проблемы подобного сорта появляются, тк по умолчанию Qt считает что Вы создаете приложение с GUI и поэтому запускает Ваше приложение как оконное.